# Adding another column with a different condition in SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, getdate

I'm trying to find different information about my data all in the same query. I want to create new columns based on separate conditions. Here is what my table looks like right now

```
 SELECT COUNT (distinct ext_project_id) as "Total Projects"
   FROM dbo.v_report_project
  INNER JOIN dbo.v_report_program
     ON dbo.v_report_program.program_id = dbo.v_report_project.program_id
  WHERE project_status = 'Active'
    AND datediff (day, creation_date, getdate()) < 15 ;
```

The outcome is:

```
Total Projects
163
```

Here is what I want my table to look like:

```
Total Projects | Projects Under 15 Days | Projects Between 15 and 60 Days | Projects     Over 60 Days
163                     ??                           ??                             ??
```

How can I find these different counts, all at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` to limit a particular `count` to a certain date range:

```
select  count(distinct project_id) as total
,       count(distinct case 
            when datediff(day, creation_date, getdate()) < 6
            then project_id end) as total_6day
,       count(distinct case 
            when datediff(day, creation_date, getdate()) < 7
            then project_id end) as total_7day
,       count(distinct case 
            when datediff(day, creation_date, getdate()) < 42 
            then project_id end) as total_42day
from    dbo.v_report_project proj
join    dbo.v_report_program prog
on      proj.program_id = prog.program_id
where   project_status = 'Active'
```

If no `when` matches and no `else` is specified, a `case` returns `null`.  Since `count` ignores `null` you get the proper subtotals.